# Variable value excessively long despite being defined as 1

Tags: c, string, variables, structure

One of my variables, dict2Length, is returning a whopping 1701996320 when I use a printf statement to obtain it. My confusion is compounded by the fact that this continues to be the case despite the fact that I have commented out anything that could possibly increase its value. It was originally defined as 1.

Here's my code. I apologize for the length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct entry
{
    char word[15];
    char definition[50];
};


void dictionarySort(struct entry dictionary[]) {
    int i, j, k, word1, word2, dict2Length = 1;
    bool bnf = false;
    struct entry dictionary2[100] = {{}};

    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(&dictionary->word[0]); i++) {
        strcpy(&dictionary2[0].word[i], &dictionary[0].word[i]);
    }


    i = 0;
    word1 = 1;
    word2 = 0;

    while (isalpha(dictionary[word1].word[0])) {

        while (i <= strlen(&dictionary->word[word1])) {
            //printf("%c", dictionary[word1].word[i]);
            if (dictionary[word1].word[i] == dictionary2[word2].word[i]) {
                i++;
                bnf = false;
            }
            else if (dictionary[word1].word[i] < dictionary[word2].word[i]) {
                //insert section to prevent back-and-forth cycling
                if (bnf == false) {
                    word2--;
                    bnf = true;
                }
                else { //(dictionary[word1].word[i] < dictionary[word2].word[i])
                    //open up new index by moving everything above up one, insert at word
                    for (j = dict2Length; j > word2; j--) {
                        //word
                        for (k = 0; k <= strlen(&dictionary2->word[0]); k++) {
                            strcpy(&dictionary2[j+1].word[k], &dictionary2[j].word[k]);
                        }
                        //definition
                        for (k = 0; k <= strlen(&dictionary2->word[0]); k++) {
                            strcpy(&dictionary2[j+1].definition[k], &dictionary2[j].definition[k]);
                        }
                    }

                    //for (k = 0; k < strlen(&dictionary1->word[word1]))
                    for (k = 0; k < strlen(dictionary[word1].word); k++) {
                        strcpy(&dictionary2[word2].word[k], &dictionary[word1].word[k]);
                        //printf("one\n");
                    }
                    for (k = 0; k < strlen(dictionary[word1].definition); k++) {
                        strcpy(&dictionary2[word2].definition[k], &dictionary[word1].definition[k]);
                        //printf("two\n");
                    }
                    //dict2Length++;
                    break;
                }   
            }
            else {
                //insert section to prevent back-and-forth cycling
                if (bnf == false) {
                    word2++;
                    bnf = true;
                }
                else { //(dictionary[word1].word[i] < dictionary[word2].word[i])
                    //open up new index by moving everything above up one, insert at word
                    for (j = dict2Length; j > word2; j--) {
                        //word
                        for (k = 0; k <= strlen(&dictionary2->word[0]); k++) {
                            strcpy(&dictionary2[j+1].word[k], &dictionary2[j].word[k]);

                            //printf("%d", word1);
                        }
                        //definition
                        for (k = 0; k <= strlen(&dictionary2->word[0]); k++) {
                            strcpy(&dictionary2[j+1].definition[k], &dictionary2[j].definition[k]);
                            //printf("two\n");
                            //printf("%d", word1);
                        }
                    }

                    for (k = 0; k < strlen(dictionary[word1].word); k++) {
                        strcpy(&dictionary2[word2].word[k], &dictionary[word1].word[k]);
                        //printf("three\n");
                        //printf("%d", word1);
                    }

                    for (k = 0; k < strlen(dictionary[word1].definition); k++) {
                        strcpy(&dictionary2[word2].definition[k], &dictionary[word1].definition[k]);
                    }
                    //dict2Length++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        word1++;
    }

    word2 = 0;
    printf("dict2Length = %d", dict2Length);
    //for (i = 0; i < dict2Length; i++) {
        //printf ("%s\n", dictionary2[i].word);
    //}

}

int main (void) {
    struct entry dictionary[100] = 
    {{"aerie", "a high nest"},
    {"abyss", "a bottomless pit"},
    {"ahoy", "a nautical call of greeting"},
    {"addle", "to become confused"},
    {"aardvark", "a burrowing African mammal"},
    {"agar", "a jelly made of seaweed"},
    {"acumen", "mentally sharp; keen"},
    {"aigrette", "an ornamental cluster of feathers"},
    {"affix", "to attach"},
    {"ajar", "partially opened"}};
    dictionarySort(dictionary);
}
```

Comment: Most likely due to stack corruption resulting from overflowing the dictionary2 array

Comment: Agree with samgak. Use a debugger. Put a watch on dict2Length, step through the code and you will likely be able to find a line of code that changes dict2Length.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you're copying strings wrong and corrupting your stack.  Your loop looks like it it is trying to copy one character at a time, you iterate i through each character, but then you go and do a strcpy at each character. strcopy copies all characters up the a null so you don't need to do the loop yourself.

```
>     for (i = 0; i <= strlen(&dictionary->word[0]); i++) {
>         strcpy(&dictionary2[0].word[i], &dictionary[0].word[i]);
>     }
```

I think you probably mean to do something something more like the below instead with no per-character loop to copy the string.

```
>     
>     strcpy(dictionary2[0].word, dictionary[0].word);
>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to duplicate the contents of word in `dictonary` to `dictionary2` then the following code

```
for (i = 0; i <= strlen(&dictionary->word[0]); i++) {
    strcpy(&dictionary2[0].word[i], &dictionary[0].word[i]);
}
```

should be replaced with the below one

```
for (i = 0; strlen(dictionary[i].word); i++) {
    strcpy(dictionary2[i].word,dictionary[i].word);
}
```

Comment: Or `memcpy (dictionary2, dictionary, sizeof (structy entry) * 100)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes,best and efficient method for copy activities.

Answer (score 0):

It took a white to figure out just what you are trying to do? Your use to the urnary operator with the struct made no sense. I still might not have it 100% right, but it appears all your code was an attempt to sort the struct. I don't know if you have constraints forcing you to attempt a manual sort, but the normal approach is us to use an algorithm like `qsort` to sort the struct for you. Now, you can sort the entire struct, but that will sort the empty elements first. To avoid this issue, send `qsort` only the number of elements that contain words. A quick hack to determine the number of filled elements is simply to check whether the first char in `words` exists. Combining all of the above, your sort of the `dictionary` struct can be reduced to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct entry
{
    char word[15];
    char definition[50];
};

int dictcompare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    struct entry *sa = (struct entry *)a;
    struct entry *sb = (struct entry *)b;
    return strcmp (sa-> word, sb-> word);
}

int main (void) {

    size_t num_entries = 0;
    size_t i = 0;

    struct entry dictionary[100] = 
    {{"aerie", "a high nest"},
    {"abyss", "a bottomless pit"},
    {"ahoy", "a nautical call of greeting"},
    {"addle", "to become confused"},
    {"aardvark", "a burrowing African mammal"},
    {"agar", "a jelly made of seaweed"},
    {"acumen", "mentally sharp; keen"},
    {"aigrette", "an ornamental cluster of feathers"},
    {"affix", "to attach"},
    {"ajar", "partially opened"}};

    /* count the number of filled entries in dictionary */
    while (*dictionary[num_entries++].word);
    num_entries--;

    /* print the unsorted entries */
    printf ("\ndictionary:\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < num_entries; i++)
        printf (" %-15s : %s\n", dictionary[i].word, dictionary[i].definition);

    /* sort the dictionary entries using qsort */
    qsort (dictionary, num_entries, sizeof (struct entry), dictcompare);

    /* print the unsorted entries */
    printf ("\ndictionary (sorted):\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < num_entries; i++)
        printf (" %-15s : %s\n", dictionary[i].word, dictionary[i].definition);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/struct_dictionary

dictionary:

 aerie           : a high nest
 abyss           : a bottomless pit
 ahoy            : a nautical call of greeting
 addle           : to become confused
 aardvark        : a burrowing African mammal
 agar            : a jelly made of seaweed
 acumen          : mentally sharp; keen
 aigrette        : an ornamental cluster of feathers
 affix           : to attach
 ajar            : partially opened

dictionary (sorted):

 aardvark        : a burrowing African mammal
 abyss           : a bottomless pit
 acumen          : mentally sharp; keen
 addle           : to become confused
 aerie           : a high nest
 affix           : to attach
 agar            : a jelly made of seaweed
 ahoy            : a nautical call of greeting
 aigrette        : an ornamental cluster of feathers
 ajar            : partially opened
```